# Segmentation Fault with OpenMP Tasks in Subroutines (Intel Fortran 2018 Update 1)

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, openmp, intel-fortran

I ran into the following problem when using the Intel Fortran 2018 Update 1 Compiler.  I implemented a block algorithm to compute  an out-of-place triangular matrix-matrix product  `C := alpha * A * B + beta *C`, where A is a upper triangular matrix. Since the matrix matrix product has a great potential for parallelization I did this using OpenMP tasks and task dependencies. Ending up with the following code:

```
SUBROUTINE DTRMM3(M,N,ALPHA,A,LDA,B,LDB,BETA,C,LDC)
USE OMP_LIB
IMPLICIT NONE
DOUBLE PRECISION ALPHA,BETA
INTEGER LDA,LDB,LDC,M,N
DOUBLE PRECISION A(LDA,*),B(LDB,*),C(LDC,*)
EXTERNAL DGEMM, DTRMM
INTRINSIC MAX
INTEGER K,KB,L,LB,J,JB
!     .. Parameters ..
DOUBLE PRECISION DONE,DZERO
PARAMETER (DONE=1.0D+0,DZERO=0.0D+0)
INTEGER NB
PARAMETER(NB=256)
!     .. Local Work...
DOUBLE PRECISION TMP(NB,NB)

IF (M.EQ.0 .OR. N.EQ.0) RETURN

IF (ALPHA.EQ.DZERO) THEN
    DO J = 1,N
        !$omp simd safelen(64)
        DO K = 1,M
            C(K,J) = BETA * C(K,J)
        END DO
        !$omp end simd
    END DO
    RETURN
END IF

DO L = 1,N,NB
    LB = MIN(NB,N - L + 1)
    DO K = 1,M,NB
        KB = MIN(NB, M - K + 1)
        !$omp task firstprivate(K,KB,L,LB) depend(inout: C(K:K+KB-1,L:L+LB-1)) shared(C,BETA)
        C(K:K+KB-1, L:L+LB-1) = BETA * C(K:K+KB-1,L:L+LB-1)
        !$omp end task
        DO J = K, M, NB
            JB = MIN(NB, M - J + 1)
            !$omp task firstprivate(K,KB,L,LB, J, JB) private(TMP) &
            !$omp& depend(in:A(K:K+KB-1,J:J+JB-1), B(J:J+JB+1,L:L+LB-1)) depend(inout: C(K:K+KB-1,L:L+LB-1)) &
            !$omp& shared(ALPHA,A,B,C,LDA,LDB,LDC) default(none)
            IF ( K .EQ. J ) THEN
                TMP(1:KB,1:LB) = B(K:K+KB-1,L:L+LB-1)
                CALL DTRMM("L","U","N","U", KB, LB, ALPHA, A(K,K), LDA, TMP, NB)
                C(K:K+KB-1, L:L+LB-1) = C(K:K+KB-1,L:L+LB-1) + TMP(1:KB,1:LB)
            ELSE
                CALL DGEMM("N", "N", KB, LB, JB, ALPHA, A(K,J), LDA, B(J,L), LDB, DONE, C(K,L),LDC)
            END IF
            !$omp end task
        END DO

    END DO
END DO
RETURN
END SUBROUTINE
```

and execute it using:

```
!$omp parallel
!$omp master
CALL DTRMM3(M, N, ALPHA, A, LDA, B, LDB, BETA, C2, LDC)
!$omp end master
!$omp taskwait
!$omp end parallel
```

The whole example can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/grisuthedragon/f3c9099dda48d3ab73746298663b84b3)

I compiled the code using view source

```
ifort -xHost -O3 dtrmm3_test.f90  -qopenmp -mkl -g
```

and executing it on a 16-core Xeon Silver 4110 leads to a segmentation fault:

```
./a.out
512   786     0.00000000D+00   0.00000000D+00   0.00000000D+00  T
512   786     0.00000000D+00   0.10000000D+01   0.00000000D+00  T
512   786     0.00000000D+00   0.20000000D+01   0.00000000D+00  T
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
```

The first three lines show that the path ALPHA=0.0 works and it only crashes when the task-based part of the algorithm is called.

Uisng GCC 7.3 and Netlib BLAS everything works fine without an error.

OS: CentOS 7.4 , Intel Fortran 2018 Update 1, MKL 2018 Update 1

Answer (score 1):

We're taking a look at this (compiler and OMP runtime team at Intel) and will get back to you soon.

Meanwhile, note that on your innermost loop tasks, I think you want to add "C" to your shared list, since you have a "default(none)" there.  The compiler should have warned you about that (I've noted the C++ compiler does, Fortran does not, so that's a bug).

Revised answer: Our compiler team says there is an error in usage of shared clauses inside the subroutine here - you get shared access to C in the subroutine, but not the C2 in main.

For reference, this OpenMP specification note in TR6:
"Note – Passing a shared variable to a procedure may result in the use of temporary storage in place of the actual argument when the corresponding dummy argument does not have the VALUE attribute and its data-sharing attribute is implementation-defined as per the rules in Section 2.20.1.2 on page 243. These conditions effectively result in references to, and definitions of, the temporary storage during the procedure reference. Furthermore, the value of the shared variable is copied into the intervening temporary storage before the procedure reference when the dummy argument does not have the INTENT(OUT) attribute, and back out of the temporary storage into the shared variable when the dummy argument does not have the INTENT(IN) attribute. Any references to
(or definitions of) the shared storage that is associated with the dummy argument by any other task must be synchronized with the procedure reference to avoid possible race conditions."

Try this:  Move the taskwait to the end of the DTRMM3 subroutine, right before the return. When this taskwait is reached, C will still be in scope.

Thanks!

Terry

Comment: I added the C to the list of shared variables but the compiler did not warn me. (using ifort -O3  -qopenmp dtrmm3_test.f90  -mkl -warn)

Comment: I submitted two bug reports.  One for missing compiler error report for leaving C out, and one for the crash.  I was able to eliminate a few things (like task dependencies, MKL) as the cause.  I think the error is related to use of array sections, and was able to reduce to a much smaller reproducer that still crashes. I have a watch on the bug, so if we make any progress or find a workaround, I will let you know.

Comment: Revised my main answer above with the fix.

Comment: If I understand the TR6 part you referenced right, I would be allowed to to implement this in the same using C instead of Fortran, since this note only applies to the Fortran behaviour of the shared clause.  Libraries like PLASMA ( https://bitbucket.org/icl/plasma/ ) use the same strategy, creating the threads, and calling a subroutine only by the master thread, and then creating dependent tasks on the innermost level. So this is a bug in the standard?